# How to keep child frames on top of parent

Tags: wxpython

I would like to know how to keep a child frames on top of parent frame, without being modal. I tried using wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT, but all I get is a grey frame on top of my main Frame. Whether I put it in my class or when I create an instance, the result is the same.

[image]

```
bob = DpxBob(self, title = 'DIO Info', btn = CLOSE|UPDATE, device = self.device,
      size=(730, 635), tabs=tabs, style=wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT)


class DpxFrame(wx.Frame):  
    def __init__(self, parent, title, btn, device, size, tabs=None):
        super(DpxFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=size,
                    style=wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT)
```

Also, it needs to be cross platform. Any help would be appreciate.

P.S.: Making progress, but I am still new in the world of OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you need to also add wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE to your child frame's style list. Here's an example that works for me:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class GenericPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, showChild=False):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        if showChild:
            btn = wx.Button(self, label="Show Child")
            btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onShowChild)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onShowChild(self, event):
        """"""
        frame = ChildFrame(self.GetParent())
        frame.Show()

########################################################################
class ChildFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Child frame", 
                          style=wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT|wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        panel = GenericPanel(self)
        self.Show()

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main Frame", size=(800,600))
        panel = GenericPanel(self, showChild=True)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now if you want to keep the frame within the confines of the main frame, then you'll probably want to look at MDI frames in wx.aui (or better yet, check out the generic AUI in wx.lib.agw.aui). The wxPython demo has examples of each.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Seeing your answer makes me wonder if I wrote my class properly in the first place. Why use a class for GenericPanel and one for ChildFrame? Is it "better code" to do like this?

Comment: I just wanted to reuse the panel in both frames. Sometimes this is helpful, sometimes not.

Comment: Perfect! That did the job. Thanks again.